# Using Imagemagick to convert images to the video: background of the video is black, whereas the background of the pictures are white

Tags: video, imagemagick, mogrify

I created a movie file from a set of PDF files using:

```
mogrify -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 -format png ./*.pdf"
convert -delay 600 *.png movie.mp4
```

on Microsoft Windows 10 (requires  [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)  and  [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to be installed). The first command converts PDF files to PNG. The second command converts PNG files into 1 MP4 file.

When I opened the resulting `movie.mp4` in VLC, the background of the video is black, whereas the background of the pictures are white. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Most probably a transparency layer that `convert` does not handle properly. Can you share one of those PNGs?

Comment: @slhck Unfortunately I cannot :( I just wrote a python script to generate some PDF plots, but they don't have this background issue. You are correct: it looks like the issue stems from the presence of a transparency layer.

Comment: @slhck To prevent  mogrify from adding the transparency layer: `mogrify -background white -alpha off -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 -format png ./*.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As slhck pointed out in the comments, the issue stems from a transparency layer that convert does not handle properly.

To prevent  mogrify from adding the transparency layer, add `-background white -alpha off`:

```
mogrify -background white -alpha off -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 -format png ./*.pdf`
```